# How to compare ListBox text with Sheet name in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to do a User Form that allows to insert a number in a ListBox, in case this number matches with one of sheet names, to select this work sheet. In case there is not a match, to give a message box, that the number was not found.
But i have a problem with defining that the ListBox text must be compared with Sheet names.
It looks in a following way:

[image]

The code is following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Option Explicit
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        'this line i could not manage
        If ws.Name Like "Tel*" Then
        Sheets("Tabella Riepilogativa").Select
        End If
        Else: MsgBox "Phone number was not found"
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub
```

Can someone help with it, please?

Comment: maybe `if StrComp(ws.name, textbox1,vbtextcompare) = 0 then`

Comment: Why are you using a `listbox` for a users input? Could you not use a `textbox` instead?

Comment: yes, for user input. I think i can substitute with textbox, but still i dont know how to compare with sheet names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Option Explicit` belongs at the top of the file.

To find a sheet named `"Tel{whatever the user entered in a TextBox}"`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, wsFound As Worksheet, searchFor As String

searchFor = "TEL" & UCase$(Trim$(TextBox1.Text))

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If UCase$(ws.Name) = searchFor Then
        Set wsFound = ws
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If wsFound Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not Found (I should probably be a label to save the user an unnecessary click)"
Else
    wsFound.Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You! The script runs perfectly. The only problem is that it always says "Not Found", even if the textbox and Sheet name were equal.
The other thing, is it possible to do the same operation also with numbers, or just with text?

Comment: If the user enters 123 it will select a sheet called "tel123" if you see a message box its not finding a match